# Compilation errors using qt 4.8.5 on capybara-webkit

Tags: windows, qt, capybara-webkit

I have followed the directions at https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit for installation on Windows 7. I have uninstalled Qt and reinstalled and tried to do this many times, and I can't get it to work.

I added to qmake.conf the line

QMAKE_LFLAGS = -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++

The other line in the directions for QMAKE_RCC was already there.

When I do this command in the directions...

C:\development\Ruby193\capybara-webkit>bundle exec rake build

I get errors - starting with:

c:/Qt/qt-4.8.5-x64-mingw/bin/qmake.exe -spec ../../../Qt/qt-4.8.5-x64-mingw/mksp
WARNING: (internal):1: Unescaped backslashes are deprecated.
cd src/ && c:/Qt/qt-4.8.5-x64-mingw/bin/qmake.exe c:/development/Ruby193/capybar
/mkspecs/win32-g++ CONFIG+\=test -o Makefile.webkit_server
WARNING: (internal):1: Unescaped backslashes are deprecated.
cd src/ && make -f Makefile.webkit_server
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/development/Ruby193/capybara-webkit/src'
make -f Makefile.webkit_server.Debug
make[2]: Entering directory`/c/development/Ruby193/capybara-webkit/src'
g++ -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Wl,-subsystem,console -mthreads -o debug/w
x64-mingw/lib' -lQtWebKitd4 -lQtGuid4 -lQtNetworkd4 -lQtCored4
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-static-libstdc++'
./build/BlockUrl.o: In function `ZNK5QListI7QStringEixEi':
c:\development\Ruby193\capybara-webkit\src/../../../../Qt/qt-4.8.5-x64-mingw/inc
PKcS0_S0_i'
./build/SetUnknownUrlMode.o: In function`ZN7QStringpLERKS_':
c:\development\Ruby193\capybara-webkit\src/../../../../Qt/qt-4.8.5-x64-mingw/inc
ppendERKS_'

...

ending with the following lines:

./build/moc_RequestHandler.o:moc_RequestHandler.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV14RequestHandler[vtable for RequestHandler]+0x20): undefined reference to `QObject::ev
entFilter(QObject*, QEvent*)'
./build/moc_RequestHandler.o:moc_RequestHandler.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV14RequestHandler[vtable for RequestHandler]+0x24): undefined reference to`QObject::ti
merEvent(QTimerEvent*)'
./build/moc_RequestHandler.o:moc_RequestHandler.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV14RequestHandler[vtable for RequestHandler]+0x28): undefined reference to `QObject::ch
ildEvent(QChildEvent*)'
./build/moc_RequestHandler.o:moc_RequestHandler.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV14RequestHandler[vtable for RequestHandler]+0x2c): undefined reference to`QObject::cu
stomEvent(QEvent*)'
./build/moc_RequestHandler.o:moc_RequestHandler.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV14RequestHandler[vtable for RequestHandler]+0x30): undefined reference to `QObject::co
nnectNotify(char const*)'
./build/moc_RequestHandler.o:moc_RequestHandler.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV14RequestHandler[vtable for RequestHandler]+0x34): undefined reference to`QObject::di
sconnectNotify(char const*)'
./build/moc_RequestHandler.o: In function `~RequestHandler':
c:\development\Ruby193\capybara-webkit\src/build/../RequestHandler.h:11: undefined reference to`_imp___ZN7QObjectD2Ev'
./build/qrc_webkit_server.o: In function `Z28qInitResources_webkit_serverv':
c:\development\Ruby193\capybara-webkit\src/debug/qrc_webkit_server.cpp:479: undefined reference to`_imp___Z21qRegisterResourceDataiPKhS0_S0_'
./build/qrc_webkit_server.o: In function `Z31qCleanupResources_webkit_serverv':
c:\development\Ruby193\capybara-webkit\src/debug/qrc_webkit_server.cpp:488: undefined reference to`_imp___Z23qUnregisterResourceDataiPKhS0_S0_'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [debug/webkit_server.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/development/Ruby193/capybara-webkit/src'
make[1]: *** [debug] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory`/c/development/Ruby193/capybara-webkit/src'
make: *** [sub-src-webkit_server-pro-make_default-ordered] Error 2
Command 'make' failed

Comment: It looks like the issue is the added flag which was part of the instructions for doing this build.

Comment: It looks like the issue is the added flag which was part of the instructions for doing this build  -----   

unrecognized option '-static-libstdc++' 

I've been doing some searching on this option, but I haven't figured out the solution for the problem. Removing the switch does not work and doesn't seem to alter the error message, except the line complaining about the unrecognized option goes away.

Comment: Any luck on this ? I am facing the same problem